# What happens if a light source is present on both sides of a 1-way glass?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, refraction

My question is that if there is a light source on both sides of a dual-sided mirror (the ones where form one side it acts like a mirror and the other like transparent glass), what would happen?

Comment: For how one way mirrors work see [How does a one-sided glass work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101380/).

Answer (score 3):

I assume that when you say "dual-sided mirror" you mean a [one-way mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_mirror) (which can also, confusingly, be called a two-way mirror).

A one-way mirror is symmetric - it does not have a reflecting side and a transparent side. Instead, the "one-way" effect occurs when one side is brightly lit and the other side is in darkness - from the brightly lit side, the glass appears to be a mirror because the amount of reflected light is much greater than the small amount of light transmitted from the darker side.

If both sides of the glass are brightly lit then an observer on either side will see a superposition of their own reflected image and whatever is on the other side of the glass

Comment: @Aster17 if this answers your question, make sure to accept it by clicking the green checkmark. If it doesn't, edit your original question to make it more specific