# How to ensure light only flows in one direction?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

Consider two light sources A and B. Exclude things like scattering. Without any kind of barrier A can send light to B and vice versa.
I'm looking for some kind of material or setup where A can send to B but not B to A. I'm not much into physics and optics. I'm aware of one way mirrors but I don't know how much it blocks. Are there (practical) alternatives and how much of the reverse channel will they block?

Comment: Related (if not a duplicate): [Is one way glass possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19043/21441)

Comment: Many variants of this question have been asked on this site previously. Please read them carefully; if they do not answer your query, please edit this post to explain what aspects are missing in the existing threads.